# how return a sum of all the records happened in every month for the last 12 months in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

the table look like this
[image]

So I Got a query looking like this

```
with date_ranges (range_name, range_dates) as
              ( values ('week_0', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '6 days'),  now(), '[]'))
                      , ('week_1', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '13 days'), (now()::date-interval '6 days')))
                      , ('week_2', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '20 days'), (now()::date-interval '13 days')))
                      , ('week_3', tstzrange ((now()::date-interval '27 days'), (now()::date-interval '20 days')))
              )
                select range_name, range_dates, COALESCE(SUM("transactionTotal"), 0) total_amount 
        from date_ranges dr
        LEFT JOIN "MoneyTransactions" mt on (mt."entryType" = 'sold' AND mt."createdAt" <@ range_dates)
        group by range_name, range_dates
        order by range_name;
```

It returns a sum of every week for the last four weeks. Now I am trying to return the same thing but not for weeks but sums for the last 12 months.

I was able to get the desired dates of the last months like

```
SELECT
  to_char(now() - series.n * '1 month'::interval, 'month') AS "month",
  tstzrange(
    date_trunc('month', now()) - series.n * '1 month'::interval,
    date_trunc('month', now()) - (series.n - 1) * '1 month'::interval,
    '[]'
  ) AS range_dates
FROM (
  SELECT generate_series(0, 11) AS n
) AS series
```

I tried this and obviously its not working

```
with date_ranges (range_name, range_dates) as
              ( values (
                to_char(now() - series.n * '1 month'::interval, 'month') as "month",
                tstzrange(
                  date_trunc('month', now()) - series.n * '1 month'::interval,
                  date_trunc('month', now()) - (series.n - 1) * '1 month'::interval,
                  '[]'
              ))
              )
            select range_name, range_dates(0, 11), COALESCE(SUM("transactionTotal"), 0) total_amount 
        from date_ranges dr
        LEFT JOIN "MoneyTransactions" mt on (mt."entryType" = 'sold' AND mt."createdAt" <@ range_dates)
        group by range_name, range_dates
        order by range_name;
```

However my limited knowledge of SQL is preventing me to put all that in one query to get the desired output which looks like something like this

```
[
        {
            "range_name": "september",
            "range_dates": [
                {
                    "value": "2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": false
                }
            ],
            "total_amount": "253050"
        },
        {
            "range_name": "august",
            "range_dates": [
                {
                    "value": "2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "2020-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "inclusive": false
                }
            ],
            "total_amount": "55200"
        },
        ...
]
```

Could someone kindly give a hand

Comment: seems like you want a LAG function...

Comment: probablly, to this point I was going to compute the dates outside and then pass in the values as intervals in the query @Randy

Comment: I think that might perform better than doing those calculations on database level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a much cleaner way to get a 12 month range. Depending on what the date looks like inside `money_transactions`, you can easily use these to compare against the `create_date` column.

`to_char` returns a varchar in different formats, in my example I use `MM/YYYY` which will return `10/2019` for October 2019. You must ensure the generated series date and `MoneyTransactions` column `createdAt` date format match. You can adjust it whichever way you want however.

```sql
with date_range as 
(
   select
      to_char(months, 'MM/YYYY') as "month" -- returns month/year 10/19
   from
      generate_series( date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '11 months'), date_trunc('month', current_date), '1 month':: interval) as months 
)
select
   dr."month",
   COALESCE(SUM("transactionTotal"), 0) total_amount 
from
   date_range dr 
   left join
      "MoneyTransactions" mt 
      on mt."entryType" = 'sold' 
      and to_char(mt."createdAt", 'MM/YYYY') = dr."month" 
group by
   dr."month";
```

On a seperate note, SQL naming conventions recommend using `snake_case` and all lower case in your identifiers (tables, columns, etc), so `money_transactions` instead of `MoneyTransactions`.

Comment: It actually works though if the month have no record its not returning it, which i though that `COALESCE` was for to return `0`, excuse my sql knowledge

Comment: @bihireboris Try that, I was using an equijoin so if no record was found on the total_amount it did not show it. Updated to left join.

Comment: Bear in mind that doing this will likely mean you won't be able to use any indexes for the date column. I solved this by projecting the min and max dates of each window, and used a `BETWEEN` for the join